# Does SonarQube always require an external code coverage tool to show coverage on sonar server?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

Does SonarQube always require an external code coverage tool like jacoco (Java), Coverage (python), gcov (c/c++), in order to show coverage on a sonar server?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube by itself doesn't do any coverage. Its the job for other tools like jacoco and others.

However SonarQube can gather the "results" relevant to the project quality (of course including coverage as an important code quality metric) of the build and allows tracking of the quality over time.

Usually you run coverage tool first, it "adjusts" the code, then you run the tests in the build. Coverage tool creates some results, and only after that you run sonar plugin that processes the results and sends to the sonar qube server.

So, to answer your question: Yes, without an external code coverage tool, sonar won't produce any coverage results, and no, it doesn't have a "default, built-in" coverage tool